# When I compile NebulaGraph Exchange, Connectors and Algorithm, the SNAPSHOT package can not be downloaded

Tags: database, graph-theory, nebula-graph

When I compile NebulaGraph Exchange, Connectors and Algorithm, the SNAPSHOT package can not be downloaded. It gives the hint:

> Could not find artifact com.vesoft:client:jar:xxx-SNAPSHOT

Want to know why this hint is given. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? (i.e. just enough detail to reproduce the issue)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add snapshots to the profiles of `setting.xml` to enable downloading SNAPSHOT from the repo.

```xml
  <profile>
     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
      </repository>
     </repositories>
  </profile>
```